# Inequality Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do we go on about proving this? I know we can do this by contraposition but I can't seem to get to the desired equation

$\forall x\in\mathbb{Z}, x^2 -2x + 2 \leq 0 \Rightarrow x^3 \geq 8$

Comment: $x^2-2x+2>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: How do we arrive at that from $x^3 \leq 8$,   $\forall x\in\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: $A\implies B$ is true if the statement $A$ is false (as it is here). Statement $B$ does not matter (i.e. it does not matter whether $x^3\geq 8$ or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

$(x-1)^2 + 1 \le 0$ is not possible over reals and a false statement implies any statement